# SignalR state management

Tags: c#, signalr, hidden-field, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a grid/table that I am populating with the data coming from a scanner(USB). I am using SignalR to transfer data from API(Scanning) to client. I also have a functionality where I need to trigger a Print API when table/Grid reaches a pre defined number of rows. The Problem here is how can I manage that predefined value through SignalR.
Since it is a stateless process, I cant use hidden variable (I havent tried, but thought I can't). Also I cant go back again and again to Db (performance issues)

So my query is that, how can I whether number of rows have reached or not with every scan?

Comment: Are you talking about per-client state?  Or system state maintained on the server?

Comment: > (I havent tried, but thought I can't).: Maybe you should try. When I use SignalR, I usually use a dictionary to preserve userstate based on connection id